# fork a forked project with the original acount

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have a project on GitHub called `A` and my user is `user1`. Later, another user, `user2` forked my project `A` to his new project `B`. Now he changed enough my original project (and the name of the project) and I want to fork his project `B` to another project in my account. I expected that when I pushed fork button, a `C` project was created in my account, but instead of it, the browser redirected me to the original project `A`.

I know I can pull the changes made in project `B` again to my project `A`, but the changes in `B` are important and I want to create another project. I can create a new branch in project `A`, but I don't like this approach.

It is possible to actually create the project `C` in my account (maybe with a 3rd new name)? How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: I don’t think this is actually possible on GitHub, as you will only ever have the chance to get back to your original project from user2’s fork. It might be possible to achieve this from the API (as GitHub often hides unusual features from the interface). Another way would be to just create a new project `C` in your account and push your forked repository into it. That way you won’t have the link to the original projects on the GitHub website though.

Comment: What are the reasons not to pull changes of project `B` into a new branch of the project `A`? IMO this is the way to go with git philosophy!

Comment: @greydet project `B` has "mutated" enough to consider it another project and I want to mutate project `B` enough to create a new project `C`. I wrote this consideration to avoid this answer and to have alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're experiencing this for the same reason that you can't `github fork` the same project twice from the same account. It has to do with how github actually defines a fork and how it treats it. When you fork ala Github, your personal repo resulting from the fork actually shares the same identifier as the parent project. Trying to fork C from B back into the same account which owns A is thus impossible.

You should use `git` commands, it's very common to interact with multiple remotes. In your local repo, add both A and B as remotes (`git remote add <alias_B> <url_B>`) then fetch/merge/push changes from one repo to another.

Comment: yes, this is the real answer, it is *NOT* possible to fork a forked project in the same account. the best option is to create a new repository `C` and add a remote to the project `B` (besides it is possible to add project `A`). thank you to @poke and @greydet too!